# can we insert a string into the hashtable object

Tags: java

```
Hashtable ExpiryRefData;
String icdExpiry;

try {
    ExpiryRefData = CAPSUtil.getRefData(EXPIRY);
    icdExpiry = (String) ExpiryRefData.get(EXPIRY);
}
```

can any body please explain how we are actually storing the string directly into the ExpiryRefData and how we are retrieving the values in the other string variable

Comment: here we are retrieving value of EXPIRY directly from the database using CAPSUtil.getRefData(EXPIRY) function

Comment: What is "ExpiryRefData", "CAPSUtil"? Please add more code.

Comment: Hashtable ExpiryRefData; CAPSUtil is a class that directly deals with the database and using the funtion get ref data retrieves the value from the database

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `Hashtable`. Use a `Map<K, String>` instead.
If you need synchronized access, consider using a synchronized wrapper (refer to `java.util.Collections`).

(Edit: a `Map<String, String> will do. If there is special need a`HashMap` is enough.

Comment: in my project they have used this format thats why i want to know how they did it

Comment: @user4188607 If you really want to fall back to `Hashtable` you can also make use of generics: declare `Hashtable<K, String>`, where `EXPIRY` is an instance of `K` (is it a `String`?). You can then use the method `put()` to put a key and a corresponding `String` value. Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: actually through CAPSUtil.getRefData(EXPIRY) we are retrieving data in format like(Expiry,20-sep-15) but my question is how we directly putting this values by equal to sign ExpiryRefData = CAPSUtil.getRefData(EXPIRY); because we use put function to add the key value pair and in second line inside the try block we are getting the value of EXPIRY i.e a key for the date

Comment: CAPSUtil.getRefData(EXPIRY) here the EXPIRY is a String

Comment: What does the method `getRefData()` return? Does it return a `Hashtable`? If you are not sure, read the documentation or insert a line `System.out.println(CAPSUtil.getRefData(EXPIRY).getClass().getName());` and post the result here. =)

Answer (score 0):

As per code stated here, `CAPSUtil.getRefData(EXPIRY)` returns a hashtable.  Then `ExpiryRefData.get(EXPIRY)` returns object which is casted to String using `(String)`. For more detils refer `CAPSUtil.getRefData(EXPIRY)` implementation.

As per [java Hashtable reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

```
public class Hashtable<K,V>
This class implements a hash table, which maps keys to values.
```

**Any non-null object can be used as a key or as a value.**